# Passing arguments to named function jshint warning

Tags: javascript, jquery, jshint

I have to use external/named functions for hover, like this:

```
     function onMouseIn(e){
      // Do stuff
     }

     function onMouseOut(e){
      // Do stuff
     }

     for (var btn_index = 0; btn_index < 3; btn_index++) {
       btn.hover(onMouseIn,onMouseOut)
     }
```

However i also need to pass arguments to the functions, so i figured out i'd use unnamed functions for mouseIn and mouseOut events and call my named functions onMouseIn and onMouseOut repectively with the arguments i want. I also want to pass the event and the jquery object. So my code becomes something like this

```
 function onMouseIn(e,btn){
  // Do stuff using arg
 }

 function onMouseOut(e,btn){
  // Do stuff using arg
 }

 for (var btn_index = 0; btn_index < 3; btn_index++) {
   btn.hover(
   function(e) {onMouseIn(e,$(this))},
   function(e) {onMouseOut(e,$(this))})
 }
```

But then jshint give me this warning

> Don't make functions within a loop.

So are there any other ways to pass arguments to named functions? If not then how can i make jshint to hide the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is suggesting to try preparing the functions outside of the loop, if possible, so they can be reused throughout the loop:

```
// ...onMouseIn & onMouseOut...

function onHoverStart() {
  onMouseIn("arg");
}

function onHoverStop() {
  onMouseOut("arg");
}

for (var btn_index = 0; btn_index < 3; btn_index++) {
  btn.hover(onHoverStart, onHoverStop);
}
```

When using `function` expressions within the loop (at least, when closures aren't needed), each iteration creates 2 new `Function` objects, with each pair a duplicate of the first. JSHint flags it as potentially wasteful.

---

Based on your comment, if one of the argument you need to provide is the iterator, `btn_index`, you can do that by modifying `onHoverStart` and `onHoverStop` to be called and used as closures for each event.

```
// ...onMouseIn & onMouseOut...

function onHoverStart(index) { // closure for index
  return function (event) {    // enclosed event handler
    onMouseIn("arg", index, event); // revise the argument order here as needed
  };
}

function onHoverStop(index) {
  return function (event) {
    onMouseOut("arg", index, event);
  };
}

for (var btn_index = 0; btn_index < 3; btn_index++) {
  btn.hover(onHoverStart(btn_index), onHoverStop(btn_index));
}
```

(For more details on closures, see "[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)" and "[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)")

Comment: but how would i pass the value of btn_index using this method?

Comment: Well, that would be a good reason for closures. Also, that expectation would've been a good thing to have noted in your question.

Comment: @User18473564 I've added an example that lets you pass along the index.

Comment: Is there any way to pass the event too?

Comment: @User18473564 I've updated the 2nd snippet to pass along the event objects. Though, can you please edit your question to list the actual arguments you need to be able to pass along? That shouldn't be disclosed only in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bind here

change the code to the following

```
function onMouseIn(arg){
  // Do stuff using arg
 }

 function onMouseOut(arg){
  // Do stuff using arg
 }

 for (var btn_index = 0; btn_index < 3; btn_index++) {
   btn.hover(onMouseIn.bind(null,"arg"),onMouseOut.bind(null,"arg"));
 }
```

Hope it helps